# MEAN stack app not opens from instagram profile

Tags: node.js, http, express, web, mean-stack

So basicly I posted my MEAN stack app website url on my Instagram profile, but when i try to open it it shows blank page, but it can be open on other browsers. Also Im trying to make Ionic app with InAppBrowser and it shows blank page. Can someone try to explain me what i need to do? My server.js

```
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = require('./app');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt')
};

const https_port = 443;

const server_https = https.createServer(options, app);

server_https.listen(https_port,"0.0.0.0");

const http_port = 80;

const server_http = http.createServer(
function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
});

server_http.listen(http_port,"0.0.0.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added CA in SSL options

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./server.ca')
};
```